# Why Magento doesn’t generate cache images again for my old products

Tags: magento

I have changed my Magento to new server. The problem is it won’t generate cached images for existing products. All becomes place holder. Only new product created is having cache image. How can I force Magento to use real images in media folder ????

Comment: did you try clearing image cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably is a permissions error as this has happened to me multiple times as well. Try if `chmod 777 media/catalog/product -R` or `chmod 777 media -R` works then investigate the right non-777 permissions for the aforementioned folders depending on your server setup. You can probably `chown` the media folder to `www-data:www-data` or `apache:apache`. Again, this depends on your server setup.

Comment: thank you. I tried chmod media/ to 777, and the cache folder can be created automatically too, but only with new product images. I'm requesting an ssh access to chown the media folder. If this is unsuccessful again, then I don't have any other method to try.

Comment: If you browse through Catalog -> Manage Products, do you see your old images there?

Comment: If I browse in admin, I can see a row in media tab, with small_image and thumbnail selected, but the image is blank. This happens only with old product. By the way, I tried to chown the media folder but it still doesn't work at all.